# cannot understand numpy.random.RandomState

Tags: python, numpy

I read the source code of Deep Learning by using Python.(Yusuke Sugomori [DBN](http://blog.yusugomori.com/post/40250499669/python-deep-learning-deep-belief-nets)).
I could not understand the meaning of 
 `numpy_rng = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)`. when I type:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
>>> a
```

it shows `<mtrand.RandomState object at 0x100412150>`

Is is right?  What meaning is this? Any idea , thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It creates a `numpy.random.RandomState` object:

> RandomState exposes a number of methods for generating random numbers drawn from a variety of probability distributions.

See [`numpy.random.RandomState`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) for the class parameters and the complete list of methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
rdm = RandomState(1)
data = rdm.rand(128, 2)
```